# Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Comment | (() => Comment)'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I've been for some hours tryin to solve this, I've made the code below using as base another component pretty equal from the same project. What am I doing wrong?

The error is exactly what I've put in title: Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Comment | (() => Comment)'. I think it's something about the interface or the state above, idk.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../services/firebase';
import { CommentListDiv } from './styles';

interface Comment {
  email: string;
  message: string;
  name: string;
}

const CommentList = ({ pokemon }: { pokemon: any }) => {
  const [comments, setAllComments] = useState<Comment>([]);
  const collectionRef = collection(db, `comments-${pokemon.id}`);

  const loadAllComments = async (): Promise<any> => {
    await getDocs(collectionRef).then((snapshot) => {
      const allComments: any = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      console.log(allComments);
      console.log(comments);
      setAllComments(allComments);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadAllComments();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <CommentListDiv>
        <h1>Comments about {pokemon.name}</h1>
        <h2>Name: {comments.name}</h2>
        <h2>E-Mail: {comments.email}</h2>
        <p>
          Message:
          <br />
          {comments.message}
        </p>
      </CommentListDiv>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CommentList;
```

This is the return of both console.logs (the return is correct, the exact entry that I've made and that's showing at Firebase too:
[image: return of both console.logs]

Answer (score 1):

```
useState<Comment>([]);
```

This says that the state will contain exactly one `Comment`, but then you try to pass an array in as the initial value. If the state is supposed to store an array of comments, then do:

```
useState<Comment[]>([]);
```

Comment: got the same result

Comment: Which line of code does typescript say the error is on?

Comment: line 13, col 56, it appers to be exacly at the useState and the problem must be because this  "setAllComments(allComments);" is apointing an array of objects idk

Comment: It's pointing to exactly the line i recommended that you change, and i have reproduced on my side that changing it the way i suggested makes the error go away. I don't know why it isn't working for you.

Comment: well, i've reopened vscode and the error changed (?), here's the new one: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Comment[]'.

Comment: same for name and email

Comment: Progress then. You'll just need to start using `comments` as the array that it is. The array *as a whole* doesn't have an email; the individual comments *inside* the array have emails. So most likely, you want to call `comments.map(comment => `, and create JSX elements for each comment

Comment: got more progress, i've managed to create a ```const result = comments.map((comment) => ({
        email: comment.email,
        message: comment.message,
        name: comment.name
      }));``` but idk  how to render that as elements now